# Apache-Spark - Weird classes with FieldAccess suffix were loaded

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jvm

During my tests on spark I see the jvm loads these 4 classes:

```
/org/apache/spark/scheduler/CompressedMapStatusFieldAccess
/org/apache/spark/scheduler/HighlyCompressedMapStatusFieldAccess
/org/apache/spark/util/MutablePairFieldAccess
/scala/runtime/IntRefFieldAccess
```

I know all 4 of them just without the FieldAccess suffix. Do you have any idea where do these classes come from ? I looked into spark source code and didn't find any clue. I find it hard to believe those classes are jvm or scalac generated since those usually combined with $ symbols.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Approach:**

You can use `-verbose:class` and `grep` to at least find out where those classes are loaded from.

The output running your program with `-verbose:class` will have the form

```
[Loaded <package>.<classname> from <pathToJar>]
```

This output can be piped into `grep` and filtered for *CompressedMapStatusFieldAccess*, etc.

**Example:**

```
java -verbose:class -version 2>&1 | grep "CharBuffer"
```

results in

```
[Loaded java.nio.CharBuffer from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.nio.HeapCharBuffer from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```